# How Can I Change My Internet Connection? Using xfce Ubuntu 18

Tags: wireless, internet

I would like to temporarily change my internet connection from my home wifi to a hotspot.  There's no option on my panel and when I open Network Connections--it's empty, nothing's there.

Comment: How did you configure your home connection?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu on an end of support Chromebook, so ChromeOS is connected.

Comment: It is unclear what are you using. Is Ubuntu installed as a virtual machine or what you mean? If ChromeOS is connected, then change the connection there.

Comment: I thought there might be a setting in XFCE. Not a problem to switch back to ChromeOS and change.  Thanks.

Comment: There is a setting in XFCE. But you set the connection in the OS you are using. If you set it up in another  OS, it won't work. Your the question is very unclear. I suspect that you connection is set without NM in Ubuntu. That disabled NM.

Comment: Sorry. I'm a total noobie with Linux.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 18, Ubuntu Core 18 is closest (specialist releases like Ubuntu Core use the *year* format, but being intended for IoT appliances there is no desktop included as they're used headless).  Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format for standard desktop/server releases. There is no xfce Ubuntu 18.